# Check if a value either equals a string or is an an array which contains a string

Tags: scala

A Scala map contains a key `X`.
The value can be either an array of Strings `Array("Y")`
or a simple String object, `"Y"`.
I need to retrieve the value from the map and test

if the value is a string,

```
mayMap("X")=="Y"
```

or, if the value is an array.

```
myMap("X").contains("Y")
```

I don't want to use an `if` statement statement to check the type first of the value first of all. One option would be to write a function which checks the value, if it is an array then return the array, otherwise create an array with the single string element contained in the map. Then the call would be:

```
myToArrayFunction(myMap("X")).contains("Y")
```

That's what I actually do in Java.

But this is Scala. Is there a better idiom to do this in one line using pre-existing functions?

Comment: so the type of your map is? `Map[String, Any]` or something like this?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: I'd rather use something like `Map[String, Either[String, Array[String]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
myMap.get("X") match {
  case None => println("oh snap!")
  case Some(x) => x match {
    case i: String => println(s"hooray for my String $i") // do something with your String here
    case a: Array[String] => println(s"It's an Array $a") // do something with your Array here
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have something like that. But wondered if there was a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

```
case class Y(name: String)

//val a = Map[String, Any]("X" -> "Y")
val a = Map[String, Any]("X" -> Y("Peter"))

a.getOrElse("X", "Default") match {
  case s: String => println(s)
  case Y(name) => println(name)
}
```

you can also use something like this:

```
//val a = Map[String, Any]("X" -> "Y")
val a = Map[String, Any]("X" -> Y("Peter"))

a.map(v => println(v._2))
```